# How do I change the data type for all columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change the datatype for all columns in my table mysql. 
For instance varchar to double.

Comment: good..change it then.

Comment: I think I want to do this to my columns also... Thanks for the wonderful idea!

Comment: If you want to do it for all `varchar` columns, you can write a stored procedure that gets the columns from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, and then creates dynamic SQL with the `ALTER TABLE` query.

Answer (score 0):

1. Changing of column types is possible with SQL command `ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN` (it does not work in every DBMS, however).
2. Usually you have to remove data anyway, so another option would be to `DROP TABLE` (=remove it entirely) and create anew with desired columns (with `CREATE TABLE`). You could also remove just the single column (`ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN`) and add a new one (`ALTER TABLE NEW COLUMN`) with the new definition.
3. Of course changing a column is so simple only as long as this column is not used in any constraints or keys
4. For syntax of the above commands see [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table myTable alter column vColumn int;
```

This will work as long as:

-all of the data will fit inside an int

-all of the data can be converted to int (i.e. a value of "car" will fail)

-there are no indexes that include vColumn. If there are indexes, you will need to include a drop and create for them to get back to where you were.